# Editar respostas para adicionar um conteúdo que não estava planejado pelo autor

Tags: debate, edição

Estava vendo as edições [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/387165/revisions) e pude perceber que o usuário que a editou adicionou um conteúdo ao código original.

Pessoalmente, quando edito uma pergunta ou resposta, procuro não modificar nenhum trecho de código e/ou informações originais da pergunta, limitando as minhas alterações a correções gramaticais e a adição da devida formatação.

A pergunta é: até que ponto edições como a mencionada acima são válidas? Aquilo pode ser considerado *correto*?

Comment: Se o autor da resposta não está de acordo, ele pode reverter. É uma opção acessível pelo histórico. O que está mais problemático nessa história é a [aprovação pelos outros colegas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/227428), não dá pra ter certeza se foi excesso ou falta de atenção.

Comment: Sim, a ferramenta de reverter seria uma boa nesse caso. Mas o ponto é se esse tipo de edição é "correta" ou não.

Comment: É aquela coisa... O sistema permite melhorar postagem de qualquer pessoa, então o fato de alguém editar post de outro está dentro da normalidade. Agora, até aonde é "correto" é muito complicado (falando genericamente, não do seu caso específico), eu também vou aguardar as respostas para ver como flui a conversa.

Comment: Sobre o específico, o autor da resposta autorizou. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/387131/como-separar-os-resultados-de-um-select-no-mysql-em-2-foreach-no-php#comment764292_387165

Comment: É verdade! Não tinha reparado isso nos comentários.

Comment: Autorizado pelo autor ou não, me parece completamente irrelevante a adição do HTML, a resposta já solucionava o problema, o que será escrito no corpo da resposta HTTP não é o importante, mas sim a estrutura (`if`, `else` e `foreach`). Pessoalmente acho até melhor apenas os "...", deixa o código menor, mais limpo e simples, facilitando o entendimento. Apenas uma opinião

Comment: Nessa aqui aconteceu algo semelhante [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387566/3774](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387566/3774). A autora da pergunta alterou a resposta de outra pessoa. Nesse caso em especifico acho que ela não sabia usar o site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você está coberto de razão, nenhuma edição deveria adicionar informações que o autor não colocou. Dá até para colocar uma reinterpretação do texto quando este é confuso demais e tem informações adicionais na página que ajudaram compreender daquela forma. Em código quase nunca devemos mexer, até mesmo quando tem informações adicionais pode ser um problema. O que dá pra fazer é **adicionar** um código que o autor postou em lugar diferente, mas alterar um existente é complicado, não quero dizer que nunca deve ser feito mas é difícil encontrar uma situação que valha a pena, e a pessoa tem que estar muito certa do que está fazendo, inclusive porque ela pode estar introduzindo problemas ali.

Eu reverti a edição do exemplo mostrado. E reverti a reversão porque não tinha visto os comentários por inteiro. Como o autor autorizou, então acabou valendo. Sinto pelo ocorrido.