# Manter o título ou alterá-lo visando facilidade de pesquisa?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, edições-sugeridas

Nesta pergunta [Por que não posso escrever este código assim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/398525/149882) eu sugeri a edição do título para:

> Operador condicional (?) apresentando problema

Porque parece para minha pessoa que facilita a busca, pelo menos em comparação com o título original, que não esclarece nada.

Pensei em colocar o erro

> "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

mas o próprio Autor da Pergunta não pareceu demonstrar tanto interesse no erro gerado pelo compilador, mas sim no seu código.

Ok, podem ter pensado um título melhor, quem sabe? Faria sentido se alguém alterasse após a rejeição, mas não foi feito.

Faz mais sentido se ela não tivesse sido alterada por motivo de [Editar respostas para adicionar um conteúdo que não estava planejado pelo autor](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7813/149882).

Mas o motivo da rejeição foi:

> Esta edição não faz a publicação mais fácil de ser lida, mais fácil de
>   ser encontrada, mais precisa ou mais acessível. As mudanças são
>   completamente supérfluas ou de fato prejudicam a legibilidade.

(opinião)
Nesse caso, inserir essa informação não atrapalha o Autor da pergunta, nem quem quiser tentar responder, mas ajuda na hora de pesquisar.

Assim sendo, não ficou claro o motivo da não alteração.

Relacionado:
[Edição de título para facilitar as buscas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3827/149882) 
[Editar título cujo contexto e resolução não condizem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4152/149882)

Comment: O título original não é bom, mas *"X apresentando problema"* não é muito melhor (apesar de especificar que o problema é em X, ainda acho que é um título "genérico" demais). Talvez se mudar para "Como (ou 'por que não posso') usar atribuição dentro de operador ternário?" ou algo do tipo... *"Faria sentido se alguém alterasse após a rejeição"* - concordo que poderia ter sido feito, mas esta é uma ação opcional e nem sempre as pessoas escolhem fazê-lo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sempre devemos colocar melhores títulos. Melhor significa que será mais fácil de identificar o problema e de pesquisa. E sempre tentando manter a ideia do autor original.

Quem sabe assim ficaria melhor:

> Por que não posso escrever um código que atribui um valor na variável em operador condicional?

ou

> Por que dá erro quando tento atribuir um valor na variável dentro de um operador condicional?

Ma mantendo a sua forma eu colocaria o operador por completo, só a interrogação não é o operador condicional.

Eu evitaria mensagens de erro, mas em alguns casos é aceitável. Com a mensagem no corpo dá para pesquisar também.

Considero que a rejeição foi equivocada, pelo menos por esse motivo e provavelmente por qualquer um. A sua edição melhora, ainda que não tanto quanto poderia. Eu iria no "Melhorar" e o faria de forma mais adequada, assim pelo menos a sua edição serviria de base para alguém deixar bem mais legível.